# Unlinking Objects

Tags: mesh, objects

I linked a group of objects together so that I can move the whole group of objects together. But now I want to unlink this group of objects.

I did not join the objects but linked them I think. It is not one object but still a group of linked objects. So I don't think Separate will work for this? I think it is Unlinking objects and not Separating Meshes (of one Object)

After reading the comments and answers, PGmath is right, I parented the objects but couldn't remember that I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have parented your objects to another object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.  To unparent an object select it and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.  This will give you 3 choices:

- **Clear Parent** will unconnect the object from all parents it is attached to.  This will also not modify the object's local transformation, i.e. undo all transformations it inherited from its parent[s].
- **Clear and Keep Transformation** does the same thing as Clear Parent, but also changes the object's local transformation to still reflect all transformation inherited from the parent[s], i.e. the object does not move.
- **Clear Parent Inverse** changes the object's parent-space transformation to equal it's local space transformation.  Note: this option *does not* clear any parenting.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a terminology issue here. "Link" usually refers to placing a copy of an object found in one file in a scene in another file. But if you combined several objects in the same file into a collection that you could treat as one, you may have made them into a group, either from the sub menu of in the fifth panel from the top of the "Object" menu of the footer of the 3D viewport in object mode, or by pressing the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>? You can remove a single object from the group by selecting the object and pressing the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>, and can remove an object from all groups to which it belongs by pressing the key combination <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>. If you want to remove the group entirely, there is no key combination, but if you have the dynamic spacebar enabled, you can press the spacebar, search for "group", which should show an item containing the entry, "Remove group", or "unlink group".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

is this what you want ? just make single user , and check up the object data